# Magento 2: Admin grid table - add new row on the fly?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, grid, knockoutjs

I created a custom UI grid table in admin. And I have a form on the same page to add new item to my custom database table(with ajax). After I added new item I need it to immediately appear in this grid table. So I decided instead of reloading whole table - is there a way to just push new row (with form data) to my grid with JS? Does Magento2 has any JS API function for that?